# Datepicker using Static resource

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources, date-picker

I have used the below code for the compatibility of browsers for displaying the date picker and its working fine

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
<input type="date" value="From" id="DateFrom"/> 
<input type="date"  value="To" id="DateTo"/> 
<input type="button" onclick="Search();" value="Search"/> 



    <script>
    function Search(){
        var fromdate = document.getElementById("DateFrom").value;
        var todate = document.getElementById("DateTo").value;
        alert('Date:::  ' +fromdate);
        ActionFuc(fromdate,todate);
    }

</script>
```

I have used this link `cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js` and saved the javascript and used it in static resource.

By using static resource in visualforce page its not displaying the datepicker.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.DateSearch}"/>
<script>
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
```

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The file name is case sensitive, you can recheck path and file name.

Comment: can you check developer console in chrome? Probably, there are invalid JS, or you make zip file and put it inside, or something else. Just check if that is loaded

Comment: Not easy to tell from the minified polyfiller.js, but I would expect that it loads other JavaScript when you set various options, so as kurunve suggests check your browser for load errors and perhaps include the multiple JavaScript files in a ZIP file static resource.